# Could not retrieve short_host: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass puppet

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to write/test a puppet manifest on a Windows local machine that does a quiet install of an executable file. Since I'm only testing on one machine I just use puppet apply. Here is my puppet file:

```
class particularnsbservice{

$pkg = 'Particular.NServiceBus-4.0.2.exe'

file { $pkg:
  ensure => present,
  name   => "C:\\Temp\\${pkg}",
  source => "puppet:///puppetfs/${pkg}",
  mode   => '0755',
  before => Exec['install_nsbus'],
}

exec { 'install_nsbus':
  command   => "C:\\Temp\\${pkg} /q /l C:\\Temp\\${pkg}.log",
  creates   => 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ParticularNSBServicecular.NServiceBus\bin',
  logoutput => true,
  }
}
```

These are the logs that are generated after I apply the manifest:

```
Wed Sep 11 11:32:54 -0400 2013 Puppet (info): Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/modules/admin/lib/facter/user_name.rb
Wed Sep 11 11:32:54 -0400 2013 Puppet (info): Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/modules/teamcityagent/lib/facter/short_host.rb
Wed Sep 11 11:32:54 -0400 2013 Puppet (info): Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/concat_basedir.rb
Wed Sep 11 11:32:54 -0400 2013 Puppet (info): Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/custom_auth_conf.rb
Wed Sep 11 11:32:54 -0400 2013 Puppet (info): Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Wed Sep 11 11:32:54 -0400 2013 Puppet (info): Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
Wed Sep 11 11:32:54 -0400 2013 Puppet (info): Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Wed Sep 11 11:32:54 -0400 2013 Puppet (info): Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Wed Sep 11 11:32:54 -0400 2013 Puppet (info): Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/user_name.rb
Wed Sep 11 11:33:02 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Creating default schedules
Wed Sep 11 11:33:02 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Finishing transaction 131507484
Wed Sep 11 11:33:02 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Failed to load library 'selinux' for feature 'selinux'
Wed Sep 11 11:33:02 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Puppet::Type::File::ProviderPosix: feature posix is missing
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Failed to load library 'shadow' for feature 'libshadow'
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/clientbucket] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/log] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/facts] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/certs/lt70121.va.nreca.org.pem] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/certs]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/state/classes.txt] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/state]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/certs] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/state/graphs] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/state]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/state/state.yaml] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/state]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/state] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/run] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/public_keys/lt70121.va.nreca.org.pem] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/public_keys]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/crl.pem] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/certificate_requests] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/state/resources.txt] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/state]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/public_keys] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/private] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/certs]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/private_keys/lt70121.va.nreca.org.pem] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/private_keys]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/state/last_run_report.yaml] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/state]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/private_keys] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/client_data] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/state/last_run_summary.yaml] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/state]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/client_yaml] (debug): Autorequiring File[C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Finishing transaction 39997452
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Loaded state in 0.02 seconds
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Loaded state in 0.01 seconds
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 Puppet (info): Applying configuration version '1378913582'
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /Schedule[daily] (debug): Skipping device resources because running on a host
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /Schedule[monthly] (debug): Skipping device resources because running on a host
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /Schedule[hourly] (debug): Skipping device resources because running on a host
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /Schedule[never] (debug): Skipping device resources because running on a host
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /Schedule[weekly] (debug): Skipping device resources because running on a host
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 /Schedule[puppet] (debug): Skipping device resources because running on a host
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Finishing transaction 40823628
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Storing state
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Stored state in 0.04 seconds
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 Puppet (notice): Finished catalog run in 0.15 seconds
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Finishing transaction 39987792
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Received report to process from [server name redacted]
Wed Sep 11 11:33:03 -0400 2013 Puppet (debug): Processing report from [server name redacted] with processor Puppet::Reports::Store
```

At the end of the apply, I get this error stating:

```
Could not retrieve short_host: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I've done some research and this error usually refers to a written mistake somewhere in the class, but both puppet parser validate and rake lint find no errors in my manifest. What could be the error here then?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does a call to `facter -p` yield the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this manifest a long time ago, but I have changed it to the following since then and the following code works on Puppet 3.2.3:

```
class nsb ($version = '4.0.2') {

  $pkg = "Particular.NServiceBus-${version}"

  package { $pkg:
  ensure           => installed,
  name             => "Particular Software NServiceBus v${version}",
  source           => "${shared_drive}\\nsb\\${pkg}.exe",
  install_options  => [ '/q', '/l', 'C:\Temp\nsbinstall.log' ]
  }
}
```